# TYPO3 v9: how to query additional external database (MSSQL)

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-9.x

I am trying to query an additional external database connection in one of my repositories. In `LocalConfiguration.php` I've defined two connections (`Default`, `External`).

```
[...]
'DB' => [
    'Connections' => [
        // Local MySQL database
        'Default' => [
            // ...
        ],
        // External MSSQL database
        'External' => [
            'charset' => 'utf-8',
            'dbname' => 'DBNAME',
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => 'someExternalIP',
            'password' => 'somePassword',
            'port' => 1433,
            'user' => 'someUser',
        ],
    ],
],
[...]
```

In my repository I want to query the external database (via Doctrine).

```
$queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)
    ->getQueryBuilderForTable('dbo.SomeTable');
$queryBuilder->getRestrictions()->removeAll();
$queryBuilder
    ->select('*')
    ->from('dbo.SomeTable');
```

Do I have to explicitly tell the `QueryBuilder` to use that particular connection? Right now I am getting an `Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException` error, as the system tries to connect via the `Default`-Connection.

```
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT * FROM `dbo`.`SomeTable`':
SELECT command denied to user 'myLocalUser'@'localhost' for table 'SomeTable'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['DB']['TableMapping']` where you can explicitly define what tables are located in which database. See also this for some more details https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Database/Configuration/Index.html

The other option is actually to use ask the Connection by name, and create a query builder out of that.

`GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getConnectionByName('External')->createQueryBuilder(...)`

I personally would go with the latter, as it is more explicit within the actual callers code what is used.

Comment: Perfect, this works (I'm using `getConnectionByName`) – thanks a lot!

Comment: getConnectionByName was a very useful hint for me, Thanks :-)

Comment: How can I use getRestrictions together with getConnectionByName?

Answer (score 1):

To work with external DB, you have to :

- configure the mapping with external database and table mapping in LocalConfiguration.php
- define the TCA for external tables in myExt/Configuration/TCA/MyExternalTableName.php
- configure the external tables/columns mapping in ext_typoscript_setup.txt

and then, the queries in repositories will work.

Sample LocalConfiguration.php :

```
'DB' => [
    'Connections' => [
        'Default' => [
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'dbname' => 'LOCAL-DB',
            'driver' => 'mysqli',
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'password' => 'PWD',
            'port' => 3306,
            'user' => 'USER',
        ],
        'externalDb' => [
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'dbname' => 'EXTERNAL-DB',
            'driver' => 'mysqli',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'password' => 'PWD',
            'port' => 3306,
            'user' => 'USER',
        ],
    ],
    'TableMapping' => [
        'MyexternalTable1' => 'externalDb',
        'MyexternalTable2' => 'externalDb',
        ...
    ]
]
```

Sample columns mapping in myExt/ext_typoscript_setup.txt :

```
plugin.tx_myext {
    persistence {
        classes {
            Vendor\MyExt\Domain\Model\LocalModel {
                mapping {
                    tableName = ExternalTableName
                    recordType = \Vendor\MyExt\Domain\Model\LocalModel
                    columns {
                        col1.mapOnProperty = uid
                        col2.mapOnProperty = name
                        ...
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```